# How do create a repeater with all nodes that requires authentication has been set to No?

Tags: kentico

Need to modify our repeater to only show the nodes that the authentication has been set to No. Can any one please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not so simple as the nodes may inherit from parent.
You can set the repeater's WHERE condition and check **IsSecuredNode <> 1**. IF the value in this column is 0 - node is set to NO, 1 means the node requires authentication. But, there is also a third value - NULL. This means the node is inheriting from the parent. And in this case you would need to loop through the parents until you find either 1 or 0 set in that column.

I would recommend maybe creating a [custom macro](https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/registering-custom-macro-methods) which will do the loop check using C# and [API](https://docs.xperience.io/api12sp) (keep in mind the performance of the loop) and return true/false for given item.